# Very simple DSL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, dsl

I want to write a `DSL` that works like this.

```
text = Screen.write do
  label text: 'Something'
  label text: 'stupid'
end
puts text => Somethingstupid
```

I don't know much metaprogramming ( I'm starting to learn it now) and the DSL tutorials online weren't really good. I think I should have something like this:

```
class Screen
  attr_accessor :content
  def initialize 
    @content = ""
  end
  def self.draw (&block)
    self.instance_eval(&block)
    @content
  end
```

The problem is I have no idea about the `label text:` part. This is maybe the most important part becasue I should later add functionality to it like `label text: 'border', border: '|' => |border|` and `label text: 'UPCASE', style: :downcase => upcase`. So how should I tackle this problem.  Any ideas and help are welcomed.

Comment: I added a "vertical" write method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're many different ways in which you can implement something like this. To keep it simple, you can just evaluate the block within a new `Screen` object and return the result.

```
class Screen
  attr_reader :texts

  def initialize
    @texts = []
  end

  def label(hash)
    # Validation + check for other keys
    texts << hash[:text]
  end

  def to_s
    texts.join
  end

  def self.write(&block)
    raise "No block given" unless block_given?

    Screen.new.tap do |s|
      s.instance_eval(&block)
    end
  end
end

text = Screen.write do
  label text: 'Something'
  label text: 'stupid'
end

p "Rendered: #{text}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Thanks to that I was able to implement all of `label`'s features. I have one more thing to ask. How should I implement a `vertical` method so that it works like this : `screen = Screen.write do//
  vertical do//
    label text: '1'//
    label text: '2'//
    label text: '3'//
  end//
end//`. Sorry for the formatting that's what the `//` are for. This should produce the string `screen.to_s = "1\n2\n3\n"`. I'm not sure how to do it since I have to iterate over the different label hashes, but I'm give a block?

Comment: pesho, with the method I've used: `str = Screen.write do; label text: '1\n'; label text: '2\n'; label text: '3\n'; end`? That is, `puts str #=> 1\n2\n3\n`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sorry but I have to do it, in the way I showed. I know that using `1\n` would be easier, but I want it this way so that I can later combine it with a `horizontal` method and use the combination of bout. First `horizontal` of `vertical` or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to have any instance methods. Am I missing something?

**Code**

```
class Screen
  def self.hwrite(&block) write(false, &block) end
  def self.vwrite(&block) write(true,  &block) end

  private

  def self.write(vlabel, &block)
    @str = ''
    @vlabel = vlabel
    instance_eval &block
  end

  def self.label(h)
    @str << h[:text]
    @str << '\n' if @vlabel
    @str 
  end
end
```

[BasicObject#instance_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) changes `self` within the block to `Screen`.

**Examples**

```
str = Screen.hwrite do
  label text: 'Something '
  label text: 'is amiss'
end
  #=> "Something is amiss"

str = Screen.vwrite do
  label text: 'Something is rotten in '
  label text: 'the state of Denmark'
end
  #=> "Something is rotten in \\nthe state of Denmark\\n"
```